# Hibernate ORM - supporting Java 1.8 Optional for entity properties

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, java-8

I'm trying to use `java.util.Optional` in some Persistent classes. Is there any workaround to make it work? 
I have tried using UserType, but its not possible to handle something like Optional without mapping it to SQL types by hand (not acceptable)
I also tried to use JPA Converter, but it doesn't support Parameterized Types. 
I could use wrapping getters and setters like, but it's more like a hack than a solution

```
public class MyClass {
   private MyOtherClass other;

   public Optional<MyOtherClass> getOther() {
      return Optional.ofNullable(other);
   }

   public voud setOther(Optional<MyOtherClass> other) {
      this.other = other.orElse(null);
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: See [Item 15: Do Not Use Optional in Setters Arguments](https://dzone.com/articles/using-optional-correctly-is-not-optional)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You cannot use the `java.util.Optional` as a persisted entity attribute since `Optional` is not `Serializable`.

However, assuming that you are using [field-based access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604865/mapping-a-functionaljava-optiontype-with-hibernate), you can use the `Optional` container in your getter/setter methods.

Hibernate can then take the actual type from the entity attribute, while the getter and setter can use `Optional`:

```
private String name;

public Optional<String> getName() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(name);
}
```

Comment: i saw this and i really have to say, that you never ever should use Optional in attributes only as return value of methods.

Comment: i saw this and i really have to say, that you can use optional whenever you want to avoid `null` in your codebase as long as you feel comfortable with it and even if everyone keeps repeating language architect who does not want to have "monadic-ish" composition of "optionality" in the core library in favor of insisting to use Hoars 1 billion dollar mistake. Just make sure to safeguard against external libraries/apis" that come around with nullish objects and you will be fine.